# Exception creating bean of class

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans, struts1

I'm a newbie to struts, have to learn them for work, im using struts 1.3 and I'm trying to make a simple age check app, it doesnt have any business logic as of yet I simply want it to forward to the correct pages I'll figure out the rest later,but im getting the following exception:

```
type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /welcome.jsp at line 15

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /welcome.jsp at line 15

12:         <div style="color:red">
13:             <html:errors />
14:         </div>
15:         <html:form action="/CheckAge.do"  >
16:             User Name : <html:text name="CheckAgeAppForm" property="name" /> <br>
17:             Password  : <html:text name="CheckAgeAppForm" property="age" /> <br>
18:             <html:submit value="Check Age" />


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:575)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:462)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)



root cause 
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Exception creating bean of class coreservlets.CheckAgeAppForm: {1}
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:916)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:845)
    org.apache.jsp.welcome_jsp._jspService(welcome_jsp.java:134)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)



root cause 
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Exception creating bean of class coreservlets.CheckAgeAppForm: {1}
    org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag.initFormBean(FormTag.java:463)
    org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag.doStartTag(FormTag.java:433)
    org.apache.jsp.welcome_jsp._jspx_meth_html_005fform_005f0(welcome_jsp.java:169)
    org.apache.jsp.welcome_jsp._jspService(welcome_jsp.java:118)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

The action mapping of struts-config:

```
<action-mappings>


<action
    path="/CheckAge"
    type="coreservlets.CheckAgeAppAction"
    name="CheckAgeAppForm"
    scope="session"
    validate="false"
    input="/welcome.jsp">
<forward name="UnderAge" path="/UnderAge.jsp" />
</action>
    <action path="/welcome" forward="/welcome.jsp"/>
</action-mappings>
```

form-bean of struts-config:

```
<form-bean
            name="CheckAgeAppForm"
            type="coreservlets.CheckAgeAppForm"/>
    </form-beans>
```

The welcome.jsp file contents:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="color:red">
            <html:errors />
        </div>
        <html:form action="/CheckAge.do"  >
            User Name : <html:text name="CheckAgeAppForm" property="name" /> <br>
            Password  : <html:text name="CheckAgeAppForm" property="age" /> <br>
            <html:submit value="Check Age" />
        </html:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The web.xml portion :

```
<!-- Standard Action Servlet Mapping -->
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

The action form CheckAgeAppForm:

```
package coreservlets;

import org.apache.struts.action.*;

public class CheckAgeAppForm extends ActionForm {

    private String name;
    private String age;

    public String getName(){
        return (name);
    }
    public String getAge(){
        return (age);
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name= name;
    }
    public void setAge(String age){
        this.age = age;

    }



}
```

the CheckAgeAppAction:

```
package coreservlets;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.struts.action.*;

public class CheckAgeAppAction extends Action
{
            public ActionForward execute(
                      ActionMapping mapping,
                      ActionForm form,
                      HttpServletRequest request,
                      HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{
                      return mapping.findForward("UnderAge");
                      }
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any help with this its frying my brain, thanks in advance

UPDATE:included the Action, also action mapping updated

Comment: `Exception  creating bean of class` indicates there was an exception while creating the instance - you just didn't include it. Please post the entire stacktrace in a nice format (correct intendation etc.) otherwise people might be unwilling to dig through piles of code.

Comment: Sorry , I've edited the post to include the full error. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this problem among other ones which followed. The jsp file uses the `.do` :

```
<html:form action="/AgeCheck.do"  >
```

The action mapping has no .do :

```
<action
            path="/AgeCheck"
            type="coreservlets.CheckAgeAppAction"
            name="AgeCheckForm"

            >   

            <forward name="UnderAge" path="/UnderAge.jsp" />


</action>
```

Following is the Error I had

> No action instance for path could be created

This was caused by the file structure of my project which meant that the java files were not being compiled, by default the java files were stored here:
[image: Default Location]

I've Moved those exact Files with no changes to here :
[image: New Location]

And Hey presto everything works :-) Hopefully this will help someone in future,
thanks everyone for help, I can't upvote yet unfortunately.

Comment: That... doesn't make any sense, though I'm glad you were able to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

If your posted Struts config is that you have in you app, I see there one error, you haven't included forward tag inside your action mapping, you have closed your action before forward tag:

```
<action
        path="/CheckAge"
        type="coreservlets.CheckAgeAppAction"
        name="CheckAgeAppForm"
        scope="session"
        validate="false"
        input="/welcome.jsp">
    <forward name="UnderAge" path="/UnderAge.jsp" />
</action>
```

Comment: I've updated this and still getting the very same error unfortunately :( Iv updated the above files

Comment: What exact version of Struts 1 are you using?

Comment: I'm using Struts 1.3.1 on this particular project, I'v also downloaded 1.3.5 and attempted to run a new project where I'm also getting Exception creating bean of class error, which makes me suspicious :-/

Comment: I'm beginning to think should i start completely over with new install of tomcat and struts, and new workspace in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

There should be something like `caused by` below `root cause` inside your stacktrace, so please post it also.

But anyway, one thing looks suspicious to me. Your struts config has:

```
<action
        path="/CheckAge"
        type="coreservlets.CheckAgeAppAction"
        ...
```

but [documentation](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/struts/struts1/tags/STRUTS_ACTION_1_3_0/conf/java/struts-config_1_3.dtd) for the `type` attribute says that:

> Fully qualified Java class name of the Action subclass
>                        [org.apache.struts.action.Action] that will process requests
>                        for this action mapping. Not valid if either the "forward"
>                        or "include" attribute is specified.  Exactly one of
>                        "forward", "include", or "type" must be specified.

But in the code you posted you don't have class `coreservlets.CheckAgeAppAction` - you only have a `coreservlets.CheckAgeAppForm`. Is this a mistake? Or did you just skip this for brevity?

**EDIT**: ok, a false trail - you skipped it only for the sake of brevity. Sorry, then I have no clue.

**BTW**: if I can give you some advice, don't touch `Struts 1.x`. If you have to work with it at your workplace, probably it would be better to quit this job. Struts 1.x is very weird and developer-unfriendly. Moreover, is also discontinued since 2008...

Comment: The above is the complete error page which i get unfortunatly.Iv included the action class which i think complies with the type attributes mentioned above. LOL its funny how much I've heard that since I've started this , fortunately they are going to move over to spring sometime in the future, its a large organisation, it takes a long time to get things moving.

Comment: If this is a complete error, then I'm giving up. It only proves how low-quality `Struts 1` is.